# Stripe error on checkout

Tags: stripe-payments

I am receiving the following error from Stripe after entering CC info to the popup window that the API creates.

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest' with message 'Invalid positive integer'**

The strange this is I get a green checkmark when I submit my CC info, which would indicate Stripe accepted the payment.  I see no reference to any transactions in the Stripe dashboard though.

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
      data-key="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      data-amount="100" 
      data-description="Test cart"
      data-locale="auto">
      </script>
```

Code on processing page:

```
require_once('stripeConfig.php');

$token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$orderID = intval($_POST[orderID]);
$fltGrandTotal = intval($_POST[fltGrandTotal]);

$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    'card'  => $token
));

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    'customer' => $customer->id,
    'amount'   => $fltGrandTotal,
    'currency' => 'cad'
));
```

Comment: That error is coming from your server-side code (so your PHP code or something) what does that code look like?

Comment: I updated my post to include the processing code which is throwing the error.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out my issue.  The $fltGrandTotal variable I was using to pass to Stripe was not formatted properly.